# Can I get AWS Service Health Alerts (text/email)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to receive AWS Service Health Alerts (text or email) for zones where I have my servers in?  There was an issue in EC2 North Virginia Oct 15th and I would have like to have known there was an Amazon Service issue so I can tell my client that it is not an issue with our server software.

Perhaps there is a CloudWatch metric that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes *you* can.  Sign up for the RSS feed of the zone and service of your concern such as "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (N. Virginia)".  Find this on the **[Amazon Service Status Page](http://status.aws.amazon.com/)**. When you select the small orange icon in the RSS column, your browser will prompt you to choose a service to use for viewing that RSS feed.  With the Google Chrome browser, I selected...

**Google Reader**: "Keeping up with your favorite websites is as easy as checking your email. Stay up to date: Google Reader constantly checks your favorite news sites and blogs for new content."

However, you may prefer a more direct-to-eMail news reader such as...

**Feed2Mail**: "Subscribe to any RSS feed by email using Feed2Mail service for free.
Get instant email notifications when your favorite websites are updated by using this extension and Feed2Mail free service."

Comment: I also recommend using Google News Alerts.  See http://www.google.com/alerts.  I have a watch for, "amazon ec2 service Outage".

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a setting/configuration I could activate through Amazon to do that, but looks like the feed2mail will give me the real-time alert I am looking for.

Comment: Ah, but hope-not; because eMail is not real-time.  RSS is; and that's likely why Amazon doesn't contradictorily send 'alerts' through eMail.  On the occasion of their N. Virginia data-center crashing, it ___is___ possible for them to RSS out a message to reach a 100 thousand subscribers in seconds.  To do so with eMail would take much more time, or many eMail servers working in parallel.